Why aren't large numbers working for this Ackerman Subarray Solution?
You are given two inputs for this program; <the_number> <checking_number>
For every sub-"array" you have, you need to sum up the digits of that sub-"array" and check if the sum is less than or equal to the checking_number. If it is less than or equal to the checking_number, you increase your count tally by 1.
Your total count + the_Ackerman_Number(the_number) should be your output.
The Ackerman Number of N is the least positive integer X such that 2^2^2^2... ) X times is strictly greater than N.
We are not allowed to use an array construct to solve this problem, hence the truncating of the number itself using % and /.
My code is working for all low numbers but fails at incredibly big ones.
Few of the test cases are when the_number is 11111111111111111 or 93875190871098170. How do I get over this problem? I changed my data types from regular ol' int to unsigned long long int, but to no use.
Or is it a completely different issue with my code all along?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {
    unsigned long long int number; int checknum;
    int count = 0;
    scanf("%llu %d", &number, &checknum);
    
    int size = (int)log10(number) + 1;
    
    for (int left = 0; left < size; left++) {
        unsigned long long int dummy = number % (unsigned long long int)pow(10, size-left);
        int dummysize = (int)log10(dummy) + 1;
        for (int right = 0; right < dummysize; right++) {
            unsigned long long int dummydummy = dummy / (int)pow(10, right);
            int dummydummysize = (int)log10(dummydummy) + 1;
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dummydummysize; i++) {
                int digit = (int)dummydummy%10;
                sum = sum + digit;
                dummydummy = dummydummy/10;
            }
            if (sum <= checknum) {count++;}
        }
    }
    int num = 2;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++){
        if (num > pow(2,count)) {printf("%d", count + i); break;}
        num = pow(2, num);
    }
    
    return 0;
}



Generally, don't use floating-point functions for integer arithmetic. If needed, create your own functions (often very easy to do).

(int)log10(number) is dodgy. The 64-bit number is converted to a FP one with 53 bits of precession (multiple values near a power-of-10 can convert to an exact power-of-10, then the approximate log10 is taken. Converting to an int truncates the fraction so an approximate log10 near a whole number potentially off-by-1 when converted to an int.
All-in-all, not a good way to find size.
Avoid FP for an integer problem.
Replace (int)log10(some_unsigned_long_long) with integer based code.
For a one-liner:
size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%llu", some_unsigned_long_long);

A simply do() loop involving / and % can find the size with integer math - leave that for OP to discover.

An almost good alternate:
int n1, n2;
scanf(" %n%llu%n %d", &n1, &number, &n2, &checknum);
// Count of digits (and optional sign) characters scanned to determine `number`.
size = n2 - n1;


(int)pow(10, right) is problematic too when right exceeds maybe 9 (1010 is commonly outside int range).  Stick to unsigned long long.
Even better, use integer math, not FP, to solve this task.
